# How to scroll to an element (specific table row) with protractor on a non-angular app

Tags: protractor

Tried ways but nothing is working.

```
   sgpt.scroll.scrollTo(element).then(function() { });

  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);

 browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,700);')
```

Comment: `browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', el.getWebElement());`

Comment: Please show th HTML code of table and a screenshot of  your table so that we  can  know your table has self scrollbar or not?